# Mysql create or update lock

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, locking

I have a stored procedure which simulate a create or update.

Here is my Algorithm:

```
SELECT Id INT rId FROM MY_TABLE WHERE UNIQUE_FIELD = XXX LIMIT 1;

IF (rId is not null) THEN 
UPDATE ELSE INSERT
```

The problem is that i got duplicates. How can i prevent theses duplicates? I can't add an UNIQUE INDEX because some fields can be NULL.

Thank you.

EDIT: I'm using InnoDB. Does row lock can helpme ? Locking the whole table is not acceptable for performance reason.

Comment: The primary key should never be null.

Comment: You need to use a transaction or lock the table around the two statements.

Comment: My "primary key" is composed with 3 columns. One of them could be null. That's right. I can't change the table definition...

Comment: @Barmar: Performance is important. Something like LOCK TABLE t AS myalias READ; or START TRANSACTION; / COMMIT; will do the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a transaction along with the `FOR UPDATE` clause in `SELECT`. This will just lock that one row, and should not block transactions that use other rows of the table.

```
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT id as rId FROM my_table
WHERE unique_field = XXX LIMIT 1
FOR UPDATE;

If (rId IS NOT NULL) THEN
    UPDATE ...
ELSE
    INSERT ...
END;

COMMIT;
```